# Insert a relation

Tags: android, greendao

I have a relation: an order contains many order-items. I'd like to insert it a single statement rather than: inserting order, obtaining generated order id, setting order-id for every order-item and finally inserting order-items.

For instance:

```
Order newOrder = new Order();
o.setItems(orderItems);
o.insert();
```

instead of:

```
Order newOrder = new Order();
newOrder.insert();
foreach orderItems : orderItem.setOrderId(newOrder.getId());
orderItems.insert();
```

Thanks.

Comment: take a look at the pseudo-code

Answer (score 0):

greenDAO does not support this.

Updating lists of related entities is not trivial because items could be added, updated, or deleted. greenDAO is not Hibernate, so you need to do those things manually.